# R Markdown stops working, after installing MRO

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've been building an HTML document with RMarkdown, and everything was going ok, until I installed Microsoft R open (3.3.2) and now everytime I try "Knitr HTML" it returns the following:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RevoUtilsMath', details:
  call: NULL
  error: To use RevoUtilsMath you must first install the MKL Math Library.
Visit http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download.
If you have previously installed the MKL Math Library,
remove it using Add/Remove Programs, then re-install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RevoUtilsMath'
Execution halted
```

I also re-installed the MRO, just to understand if something went wrong during the installation, and it still returns that error.

I was wondering if someone had the same difficulty and would like to share how to fix this. I have no idea on how installing MRO has such an influence in R markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this isn't necessarily an issue with RMarkdown, but a compatibility issue with RevoUtilsMath and the MKL libraries. It's referenced on the github for RRO (which Microsoft acquired and is now MRO) here:

https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RRO/issues/152

I haven't experienced the error myself, but there is a google group which references and solves that issue here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rropen/jKfR40DcIbE

The third response down is the users solution, and just below that is a microsoft support rep explaining how to properly setup MKL and RevoMathUtils. Hope that helps!